# PHPmailer with different email address for authentication and setfrom

Tags: phpmailer

I am using one Gmail account for authentication and another Gmail  address in the reply-to in PHPmailer. Emails are going properly but not sure if it is a good practice in terms of email deliverability.

Your comments will be highly appreciated.

```
<?php
  $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
  $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->SMTPSecure = "TLS";
  $mail->Port       = 587;
  $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
  $mail->Username   = "abc@gmail.com";
  $mail->Password   = "emailpassword";
  $mail->setFrom('xyz@gmail.com', 'Sender Name');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this to a limited degree with gmail.

Gmail allows you to define aliases for your account, and you can use those as from addresses in addition to the address you use for sign-in. In gmail, click the settings icon, and go to the "Accounts and import" tab. Click the "Add another email address" link and you'll get this pop-up:

[image: Adding an alias in gmail]

Enter your details and you'll have a new address that you can use as your from address.

In your PHPMailer script you'll then be able to do exactly what you're doing in your script, having different addresses in `Username` and `From`. Note that this doesn't mean that you can use arbitrary addresses as you still have to define all aliases within your account first.

If this is on a contact form, don't try to use the submitter's address as the from address; that's what reply-to is for, as [the example contact form provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/contactform.phps) shows.

Minor aside: `$mail->SMTPSecure = "TLS";` should be `$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";`.

Comment: please note that this way you actually have to confirm that you own the other account

Comment: Well, yes; it doesn't allow you forge sender addresses.